# 45 Degree Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I get google maps to tilt and display a 45% view?

Documentation says that it should do it "automatically", but it doesn't seem to be doing it.  Is this a feature Google is holding back from the API?

Click the link to and zoom in to see the feature as it is used on google maps
[Google Offices](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600+amphitheatre+parkway+in+mountain+view&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&gl=us&ei=MqJBTfXzNpC2sAPv1qHzCg&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ8gEwAA)

```
<html> <head>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" type="text/javascript"></script> </head> <body>

<div id="Map" style="width: 100%;height: 500px"> </div>

<script>
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4219720,
-122.0841430);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            scrollwheel: false, 
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), myOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(CreateMarker(map,37.4219720,-122.0841430).getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);


function CreateMarker(map, latitude, longitude){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),        
        map: map,        
    });

    return marker; } </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: How do you get the map to tilt? I can't do it on my desktop PC with your link. I have seen this feature on Android - IIRC it uses multitouch gestures.

Comment: What do you mean by "tilt" exactly? Like, isometric view?

Comment: birds eye... zoom in on google's maps and you get a 45% tilt, zoom in on a map created from their API and you get no 45% tilt

Comment: I still don't see it. If I zoom in all the way, there's still no tilt. Keep zooming in, and I get street view.

Comment: Are you in Satelite? (using the Google Offices link)

Answer (score 4):

Here is demo of using the 45 degree satellite imagery:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-rotation.html

The methods you are looking for are setTilt() and setHeading().
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

**Note:** 45 degree imagery is only available at certain zoom levels (18,19,20) and certain areas.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.518970, -122.672899),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // changes map to use 45 degree imgary
  map.setTilt(45);
  map.setHeading(90);
}
```

Comment: from their website: The existing google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE and google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID map types support 45° perspective imagery at high zoom levels (where available). That means they just want you to use google earth, and they don't bother adding matrix transforms written in javascript. Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google Maps on desktop browsers can't tilt maps by itself; only Google Earth, the Google Earth browser-plugin and the Android app can do that (currently).

Could you provide a link to the documentation that says that it should tilt automatically?

The page at the link you provide only switches on the plugin if you have it (obviously) and select the 'Earth' button on the top right.

When HTML 5 is supported more widely, I’m guessing Google Maps will be able to use vector graphics as well.  Till then, it’s tiled bitmaps or the Earth plugin, I’m afraid.

Comment: It's not actually a tilt.... its a 45% image from a ghetto bird (helicopter) or something

Comment: I don't know if we're talking about the same thing, but I can smoothly change the inclination of the map from 0° to almost 90°.  Isn't that tilting?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I though Marty (op) originally asked for the tilted view of "satelite imagery" (3D transforms of the 2D satelite images) as opposed to the aerial photage of specific cities that have been added to GMaps over the past years.

Google Maps has this feature (tilted view / two different angles), through the "tilt view" control from maps.google.com. (the API is there map.setTilt(), it just isn't enabled).

Google earth used to have this feature, now it seems Google Earth is begin phased out, and it's features have been merged into Google Maps, with the exception of "tilted view". Another exception is the Google Maps Android API, which seems to be having it!! Especially in the Google Navigation app for Android, it makes use of that in a very cool way). (Supposedly done to add more value to the Android SDK over iOS).

I guess down the road it'll be made available, when other services start offering comparable services. I hope this will happen pretty soon. Are there any other map providers doing anything similar? I think Bing is just doing more aerial photos??

Comment: Happened to find this one - on the implementation of the tilting - juicy stuff if you wanna roll your own tilting logic .. :)

  https://www.google.se/patents/US20130093750